# oracle PL/SQL stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have finished my first real PL/SQL stored proc, this stored proc works as expected. I am new to PL/SQL, could you please point anything wrong or bad coding ?

This code is assuming a naming convention, for example, 't_company' table will use 'companyId' as its primary key and its type is number.

Thank you very much.

```
create or replace
package body test_erp AS    
    procedure init_data is        
    begin         
       logMessage('procedure init_data');
       SAVEPOINT do_insert; 
       insert into t_company(companyId, companyName) values(gen_key('t_company'), 'IBM');
       COMMIT;
    exception
       WHEN OTHERS THEN  
            rollback to do_insert;  
            logMessage('roll back , due to '|| SQLERRM);
    end init_data;        
end test_erp;
```

It will call this function

```
create or replace
function gen_key(tblName varchar2)
return number is
    l_key number := 1000;

    l_tmpStr varchar(2000); -- not good, how to fix it  ?
begin
    l_tmpStr := substr(tblName, 3, length(tblName));   
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' SELECT CASE WHEN MAX('||l_tmpStr||'Id) IS NULL THEN 1000 ELSE MAX('||l_tmpStr||'Id)+1 END FROM '|| tblName into l_key; 

     logmessage('gen primary key '|| tblName ||' '||l_key);
    return l_key;
end;
```

Comment: Better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The biggest problem is the way you generate the key. Due to transaction isolation, two sessions running in parallel will generate the same key. This is neither specific to PL/SQL nor to Oracle. Use sequences instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your `key_gen` procedure is rather problematic.  Generating keys by doing a `MAX(key)+1` is slow and will not work in a multiuser environment.  Assuming you have two users, it is relatively easy for both users to see the same `MAX(key)` and try to insert rows with the same primary key.

Oracle provides sequences in order to efficiently generate primary keys in a multi-user environment.  You would be much better served using sequences to generate your keys.  Conventionally, you would create one sequence per table, i.e.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE company_seq;
```

Your `INSERT` statement would then be something like

```
insert into t_company(companyId, companyName) values(company_seq.nextval, 'IBM');
```

Or you could create a trigger on the table to automatically populate the primary key.

Additionally, while it is fine to catch exceptions in order to log them, you really want to re-raise that exception so that the caller is aware that the `INSERT` failed.

Answer (score 3):

Using function in your case **gen_key** is very slow and it's incorrect database-written and also very inefficiently.

So my advice is to create `SEQUENCE` that is generally used for this.Then you should create `TRIGGER` for generating new `PK` for each `INSERT` or directly add it with `NEXTVAL`.

So, your `SEQUENCE` can looks like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE YOUR_COMP_SEQ
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 999999
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  NOCACHE
;
```

Then i recommend to you use meant `TRIGGER`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AUTOSET_ID_COMP
BEFORE INSERT ON t_company
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT YOUR_COMP_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.companyId FROM DUAL;
END;
```

And finally just call query:

```
INSERT INTO t_company(companyName) VALUES('SomeValue');
```

If you don't want to create TRIGGER so you can do it directly like this:

```
INSERT INTO t_company(companyId, companyName)
VALUES(YOUR_COMP_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'SomeValue');
```

**Note:** Of course, you can create for every `TABLE` its own `SEQUENCE` and then use `TRIGGERS` for each `TABLE`.

**Note 2:** Sequences are very good but there is some problem that for example you added to table 20 rows, so `IDs` are 1,2,3, ... etc. and for example you will delete 15. row and since this `ID` 15 you can't use, anymore.

**Update:**

Answer and Solution is updated after a little discussion with **@Ben**, thanks.

Comment: I would up-vote you but I can't advocate the line `IF (:NEW.companyId IS NULL)`, it enables a user to insert a value that the sequence has not yet reached. This in turn means that the insert will fail further down the line for no apparent reason, if there's a primary key on the table.

Comment: man, this i used in my personal project and it works, without error. i know that primary keys are automatic not null, trigger is called before row is added to table so in this time, companyID is null but table don't know about it yet so then trigger is applied and row is correctly added to table with PK generated from sequence.

Comment: It will do; for a while. Until someone breaks it, which is unlikely on your personal project but other databases have multiple people working on them and multiple insert / update vectors.

Comment: Aha, so this si solution but not 100% working, okey. i'm glad to learn new things. So any advice for me? how you would create condition?

Comment: I wouldn't have a condition at all. Whenever an insert occurs a new primary key is generated, whatever the user decides to assign to `companyid`; you then guarantee that the sequence is maintained.

Comment: thanks for advice man, answer is updated, maybe now 100% correctly.